# Will my Tyre - Rim combination work

Tags: tire, size, tyre-width

Will a 26 x 1.75 tyre fit a [Exal ZX 19 rim](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/shimano-custom-made-26-deore-v-brake-fh-t610/exal-zx-19-rear-wheel)?

I'm changing the groupset as it has died - upgrade from a 7 speed Freewheel to a 9 speed Freehub. I need to change the wheel to make this work but don't want to change my tyres. The only 26" freehub that I seem to be able to get my hands on is the above 559-19C. I'm not sure if this will work with my tyres and hope someone here can help. Based on some conversion charts, the tyres are 47-559 in size.

The handful of charts that I've found show conflicting information. [LightBicycle](https://www.lightbicycle.com/newsletter/tire-size-chart-for-bicycle-rim.html) says it won't work, whereas [Schwalbe](https://www.schwalbe.com/files/schwalbe/userupload/Images/FAQ/reifen_felgen_2020/2022/reifen-felgenkombination-etrto-22-en.jpg) says it will.

I put a calipers on my current Freewheel rim - the external width is ~26mm which isn't much more than the Exal ZX rim above.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading everything correctly, the Exal rim has a 19-mm internal width (external width is not particularly helpful in determining tire fit); according to that LightBicycle chart, I think a 47-mm tire will fit.

You shouldn't need a conversion chart to figure out your tire size: it should be stamped right on the sidewall somewhere. Sometimes it's hard to find, but you should find a [something]-559 marking somewhere.

Comment: This helps, thank you. I do see that the tyre is actually 26x1.5 which is 40-559. I think I should be good with this, now.